# Clipping of rotated switch view

Tags: java, android, rotation, android-view, clipping

I am trying to rotate a `Switch` in an Android app. I am aware of the `android:rotation` parameter, but since this is a common part of the app, I am building a custom view that extends switch. By default, applying a rotation to the view keeps the original dimensions of the unrotated view, so this implementation should switch the width and height parameters to fit the new orientation:

```
public class VerticalSwitch extends Switch {

// Init method called from all constructors
    private void init(Context context, …) {
        // Rotate the view
        setRotation(switchOrientation.ordinal()*90);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int width = getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
        int height = getMeasuredHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();

        int desiredWidth = height + getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
        int desiredHeight = width + getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();

        //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
        setMeasuredDimension(measureDimension(desiredWidth, widthMeasureSpec),
                measureDimension(desiredHeight, heightMeasureSpec));
    }

    private int measureDimension(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
        int result;
        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

        if (specMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            result = specSize;
        } else {
            result = desiredSize;
            if (specMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                result = Math.min(result, specSize);
            }
        }

        if (result < desiredSize){
            Log.e(TAG, "The view is too small, the content might get cut");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This uses a method of fixing the sizing suggested [in this article by Lorenzo Quiroli](https://medium.com/@quiro91/custom-view-mastering-onmeasure-a0a0bb11784).

Here is the result (first switch), followed by a normal `Switch` with an `android:rotation` parameter of `-90`, followed by a series of normal `Switch` views with no rotation (view bounds are turned on):

[image: A row of switches with view bounds shown. The first is vertical, but placed lower than the others with the bottom half cut off, the second is correctly vertical, and the remainder are normal horizontal switches.]

You can see from the draw view bounds that the normal `Switch` with rotation is typically clipped visually, as the drawables extend outside the bounds, which retain the original dimensions of the horizontal switch. The custom `VerticalSwitch`, however, has the correct height (which is allowing the second switch to show the complete drawables), however the drawables are offset to the bottom half of the view and the drawables are still clipped below where the bottom of the view was in the horizontal configuration.

Inspecting the parameters of the sizing in the debugger suggest that the new, rotated dimensions are being applied correctly, however clipping is still occurring. What is causing the offset and the clipping, and how can it be rectified?

Answer (score 1):

No need to create Vertical custom  `Switch` you can use  `android:rotation="90"` for Vertical `Switch`

You need to give just static height to your `Switch`
Try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:rotation="90" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:rotation="90" />


    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: I'll have to give the static height a try. I had assumed that padding needed to be adjusted in the normal switch view. Thanks for the insight! (Question still open for fixing the clipping in the custom view)

Comment: @RedBassett padding not needed

Comment: @RedBasset remove padding than try

Comment: To confirm, setting the height fixes the clipping on a default `Switch` view.